# specify keyof type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to specify the key that are already defined in type?

```
interface KeyType {
 userName: string,
 address: string
}

type ValidationType = {
 userName: ValidateUserNameType;
 address: ValidateAddressType;
}
```

Those `KeyType` and `ValidationType` is being used for different things but `ValidationType` key will always be the same as `KeyType`.

I've been looking around but I got no luck

Comment: can you provide a usage example?

Comment: it's actualy as simple as that I want `ValidationType` key to be typed strictly based on the `KeyType`

so if there's someone add another key in `ValidationType` it will throw an error unless they add the key type in `KeyType` @AlonYampolski

The usage is kinda bit hard to come up, since I'm using my own library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom type that enforces same keys:

```
type SameKeys<T, U extends Record<keyof T, any>> =
    { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? U[K] : never }

// e.g.
type SameKeysValidationType = SameKeys<KeyType, ValidationType>
```

`U` must extend all keys from `T`. If `U` has more properties, they will be resolved to `never` value type. But this won't throw a compile error yet - two options here:

#### interface extension

```
interface ValidationType extends SameKeys<KeyType, ValidationType> {
    userName: ValidateUserNameType;
    address: ValidateAddressType;   // comment => compile error
    // foo: string                  // uncomment => compile error
}
```

#### Assertion type

```
// generic assert type
type AssertSameKeys<T, U extends Record<keyof T, any> & SameKeys<T, U>> = true

// this will error, when ValidationType is not proper
type AssertValidationType = AssertSameKeys<KeyType, ValidationType>
```

Above variants will work with your case. You should still evaluate and test, what you want to do with optional properties and other edge cases.

[Playground sample here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMEsB2NhQBmAhgMbBwDSwAngCo1gUIZxtwCuAzgQHLEBbYAC44XGFFwBzADSt2xACaKowLl1HjJOKRjSZ0MRhQBqxADZZFxfAFUeUfkIZM4AXkT6jrs5ev4AQWVVdRcKDwR9DAB6aLgAURxCaHIxQQoAa1ouOEIoCAE4OjgYCDgAIwpuYEU4XDhbGLjQcnU4MHywHLyChrgQjnN4eo6IJlgaOAA3Cw4KbwocYCmCDAW4AGV06houAB46GT7QfBxFHIAlYFJoRT2smghCIqPiHBoAPg-3eTYkAG1KHUcHAHk8GgBdURAk7AM45MHPYoAfgagIhcFESxWUBQGCacAAjAA6OAASTwBBIqVhOC4WAgOGwlKIZFMFisNgZODCcFp50222yex2YSOvk5MG5YW+LHQ7E4DicIjgEv8wHsfHSYQA3L84EoVGoNKqOeqgkbQsYdexYnAbgIhHh3N8HWAsOYKAR8lB9XbkhBNBJpArQ2HbXEODgHU74G5XQV3Z6+VAfXp8eg7QAmUkBdQEKWMkrGNbGOB5hwwLZCHb7Q7HECnAVXG5QO6Il4G97fABkgprwvrti+7hKUDmpdcFYLaq5jN5HmnsGrwFrItoYtNfjnPOMHyAA)

Answer (score 1):

My proposition here is to create third type which will join these two in the way you want. Consider:

```
interface KeyType {
    userName: string,
    address: string
}
type ValidationRules = {
    userName: ValidateUserNameType;
    address: ValidateAddressType;
    other: ValidateUserNameType; // this field will not be in ValidationType
}
// Validation type below is not affected by any additional key in ValidationRules
// keys are applied only if are added in KeyType and in ValidationRules
type ValidationType = {
    [K in keyof KeyType]: ValidationRules[K]
}
```

After that our type `ValidationType` will always have:

- keys from `KeyType`
- will have an error if there is no rule in `ValidationType` for a key in `KeyType`
- will skip any additional keys from `ValidationRules`

In other words `ValidationType` is fully driven by both types, and will have only keys existing in both, any key which not exists in both will be skipped or be an compile error.

Comment: thanks for the response, your answer is actually works for me, but @ford04 answer is more flexible and robust because I'm going to use the same pattern over and over